# Random Number generator to cover all numbers in the set

Tags: java, random, generator

I am writing an Android app and I want to generate random numbers.

But, Java's RandomGenerator gives me only pseudo random numbers. The numbers repeat and not all the numbers are covered.

I want something that will give me non-repeating numbers and will cover all the numbers. How do I do that?

Comment: this would not really be random would it?  it would be easier and easier to predict the next number given the set...

Comment: what about iterating through the set? :)

Comment: I think ever software-random generator will give you "pseudo random numbers".

Comment: "The numbers repeat and not all the numbers are covered" is _supposed_ to happen even in a truly random number generator.

Comment: @Randly:Louis Wasserman: You're right but my use case is for implementing shuffle for a slideshow. So, I would need pictures to not repeat and would need to display all images in the album.

Comment: @Thomas Uhrig: Then guess my use case is not to generate completely random numbers as described in the above comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put all random values you want into a List and shuffle it.

```
List<Integer> numbers = ...
Collections.shuffle(numbers);
```

This will give you unique numbers in a random order.

Comment: This seems great. This is a one time thing right? And then I access the list in a sequential order?

Comment: You can then access the list in order, and random but unique objects. You can do this if you want any limit number as well.

Comment: I didn't get the limit number part. Could you elaborate please?

Comment: Say you want a random sequence with up to 2 blue, 3 red and 5 green items. You can add them all to a list and shuffle them. You will get them in a random order not exceeding each maximum.

Comment: Hi Peter, I;m having a problem with this implementation. Here's my code.  private List<Integer> mShuffleList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); for(int number = 0;number < totalCount();number++){
        mShuffleList.add(number);
      } for(int i=0;i<mShuffleList.size();i++){
       Log.d(TAG,"SHUFFLE LIST "+mShuffleList.get(i++));
      }
      Log.d("TAG","------------");
      Collections.shuffle(mShuffleList);
      for(int i=0;i<mShuffleList.size();i++){
       Log.d(TAG,"SHUFFLE LIST "+mShuffleList.get(i++));
      }

Comment: The o/p is SHUFFLE LIST 0,2,4,6,8-------SHUFFLE LIST 5,2,0,7,1 and totalCount() is 9. Why aren't all the numbers getting added to the list?

Comment: You are only printing every second number as you are calling `i++` twice per iteration.

Comment: I realized that after breaking my head over it. Thanks Peter! Sorry for the silly mistake!

Comment: This is where stepping through the code with a debugger can be very useful. It can help you solve bugs in seconds once you get used to using it.

Answer (score 0):

You could fill a data structure with the numbers you want to loop over, then randomize the order of the elements in the structure and pull them out one by one. Alternatively, you could randomly pick indexes, and retrieve elements at those indexes. Whichever you do (you would choose the one more efficient for the specific data structure), you be sure to *remove* this element as you grab it. As you keep going your data structure will get smaller and smaller until you've received every element and have nothing left. This also ensures you'll never hit the same number twice, because you'll have removed it from your pool of possible numbers.